# Crear un trigger para cambiar estado de un registro actualizado

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla `usuario`, con un registro llamado jose cuyo estado es `user_state = 0` y quiero que el estado sea `1` cuando exista una actualización en la información.

no estoy seguro si lo que necesito es un trigger o un procedimiento almacenado.

```
CREATE TRIGGER onUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON user
        UPDATE user
        SET user_state = 1
        WHERE iduser = ?;
```

esa es la consulta que tengo pero como obtengo el id del registro actualizado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el trigger es suficiente, simplemente haz referencia con la palabra clave NEW:

`SET NEW.user_state = 1;`

No es necesario el UPDATE (ni el WHERE) ya que el contexto del trigger es el registro siendo actualizado en la tabla `user`.

Answer (score 3):

Deberías usar `BEFORE UPDATE` y la asignar con `NEW` el estado en `1`. Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER onUpdate
    BEFORE UPDATE ON user
SET NEW.user_state = 1;
```

Con la palabra `NEW` haces referencia al registro actual y con `BEFORE` antes de guardar.